# Comparing text in android

Tags: android, string, textview, comparison, ui-thread

im trying to compare a text in android to avoid refreshing texts if it's not necessary (otherwise the texts for different fields are refreshed every 50ms).

With normal texts it is not a problem. Everything works fine. 
But: If there are numbers in text the text seems not to be equal. Why?

Some examples:
"Abschaltpunkt" is equal to "Abschaltpunkt" (OK) /
"Gewicht" is equal to "Gewicht" (OK) /
"100 kg" is NOT equal to "100 kg" (NOK) /
"Abschaltpunkt 2" is NOT equal to "Abschaltpunkt 2" (NOK"

A new question after edit (the comparsion works fine now).
As you see I use the UI thread for refreshing the text. This app works in a network and receives arround 300 messages per second with different data (yes, it is necessary). Therefore I need the comparsion otherwise the thread is blocked and the app won't respond on user inputs. 
Is there another solution? Or is my solution a good one?

This is my code:

```html
 /**
  * Compares the current and new text und updates the text if necessary
  * @param RessourceID given by R.id...
  * @param New text
  */
 private void ChangeText (final int RessourceID, final String sText) { 
  try {
   TextView tv = (TextView) findViewById(RessourceID);
   // Erst prüfen ob Text ersetzt werden muss -> Spart Rechenzeit
   if (tv.getText().toString().equals(sText)) {
    Log.e(this.getClass().getSimpleName(), "Text nicht ersetzen: " + tv.getText() + " != " + sText);
   } else {
    ChangeTextThread(tv, sText);
    Log.e(this.getClass().getSimpleName(), "Text ersetzen: " + tv.getText() + " != " + sText );     
   }
  } catch (Throwable t) {
   Log.e(this.getClass().getSimpleName(), "ChangeText", t);
  }
 }
  
  /**
   * Change the text in UI tread 
   */
  private void ChangeTextThread (final TextView tv, final String sText) {
   this.runOnUiThread(new Runnable() {
      public void run() {
       
       try {
        tv.setText(sText);
       } catch (Throwable t) {
       Log.e(this.getClass().getSimpleName(), "ChangeTextThread", t);
       }
    
      }
    });
  }
```

Answer (score 3):

try this way

```
if(tv.getText().toString().equals(sText))
```

Used `.equals()` or `.equalsIgnoreCase()` method for string comparison

Comment: Right what I wanted to answer ;)

Answer (score 0):

Try below code:

```
if(tv.getText().toString.equalsIgnoreCase(sText)){
     //Do your stuff here
}
```